# python os.path doesn't work in CMD but works in eclipse

Tags: path, python-2.7

I want to walk through under current folder where the .py file is (python 2.7). However, it works in my eclipse but not in cmd. Below is the code:

```py
import os
import sys

def checkFiles(path):

    fileDict = []
    for dirPath, dirNames, fileNames in os.walk(path):
        for fileName in fileNames:
            if os.path.splitext(fileName)[1] == '.entity':
                fileDict.append(os.path.join(dirPath,fileName))
                print dirPath
    return fileDict

fileDict = []

fileDict = checkFiles('.')

print fileDict
```

Now I have 5 .entity files under this folder, so when print fileDict, it should print 5 elements in the list. However, this works fine in eclipse but it returns an empty list to me in cmd. Anyone can help me out of this please?

oh BTW, I have another problem when generate an xml file. I think it suffers the same problem. When I use eclipse, it will work fine, but it won't create any file when I use cmd.

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't use string concatenation to join paths. Use `os.path.join`.
Second, don't use `\\` for path separators. `/` is universal and works on Windows:

```
fileDict.append(os.path.join(dirPath, fileName))
```

And then when you call it:

```
fileDict = checkFiles('.')
```

And also, you are overwriting your list when you loop, by using the same variable name:

```
for fileNames in fileNames:
```

So, something like this:

```py
def checkFiles(path):
    fileDict = []
    for dirPath, dirNames, fileNames in os.walk(path):
        for fileName in fileNames:
            if os.path.splitext(fileName)[1] == '.entity':
                fileDict.append(os.path.join(dirPath, fileName))
    return fileDict

fileDict = checkFiles('.')
```

Note: This script assumes your files are located under the location from which you are running your script... *not* the location of the script itself.

```
C:\SomeDir> python C:\path\to\script.py
```

... Your files need to be under `C:\SomeDir` and not `C:\path\to\`

When you run the script through eclipse, the current working directory is that workspace. But when you run it through cmd, its whever you are in the currect directory.

Comment: Thank you so much jdi, but the problem still remain.when running in cmd, it still prints fileDict as an empty list ([]) to me.

Comment: How are you running your script?

Comment: Oh when I change the checkFile into another actual path like: r'C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\SampleEntities\SampleEntities' it works fine

Comment: You were not running the script from the same directory that contained your files. It was using relative paths

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhh yes yes that make sense now! Thank you very much!! I am starting doing research on it now. Thank you again

Comment: Very welcome. Dont forget to hit the checkmark if this answer solved the problem for ya!